# what's it called when you have a navigation that appears only after user has scrolled down a certain perentage

Tags: website-design

What's the name of the effect similar to seen on www.newyorker.com when the user scrolls down (about halfway in the case) of www.newyorker.com? It's obviously not a drop-down but what is the colloquial / ux term for that effect (like hamburger or something)? This part (highlighted in red):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call that a sticky nav after the jQuery code that's used to implement.

Comment: cool - got the sticky part but what about the fade-in; like a fade-in sticky?

Comment: You could call it that. That's more of a descriptor after the fact. So if I were putting that in annotations I would call it "sticky navigation with fade-in."

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to Johnny UX's answer, in other toolkits such position-dependent fixed navigation is called **Affix**, e.g. [Twitter Bootstrap: Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix). Anyway it seems that the term *sticky* is more widespread.

Historically, such page elements were first realized with [Mootools ScrollSpy](http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy), and as far as I know until know (2014) still implemented with Javascript. Anyway, there is discussion about a `position: sticky` CSS3 attribute.

Comment: Lacking 10 reputation, here's the link for `position:sticky` pure CSS: http://charliepark.org/css-only-sticky-headers/